# how to custom cache in okhttp3?

Tags: caching, okhttp

Our server api request always need a parameter `token` to prevent malicious access, and the `token` is generate with a timestamp which is simply use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but okhttp3 cache the key use the url which I found in the `okhttp3.Cache#urlToKey`, so the key would always change and the cache are invalid. It's a way to custom cache, so I can remove the token parameter to generate the key, and add back to the url when I get in the cache. hope I can explain what I mean with my poor English.